# How to debug Mongoose and MongoDB in a MEAN stack?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, npm, mean-stack

I'm learning the MEAN stack and I'm using `npm start` to run my application. I have some issues with Mongoose and MongoDB but all I get is `POST /page 500 63.925 ms - 961`

This is the directory structure of my app, based on [this tutorial](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial):

```
HTML        views/
Angular.js  public/javascript/
Express.js  routes/
Node.js     app.js
Mongoose js models/, connected in app.js
Mongo db    connected in app.js
```

What can I do to get helpful Mongoose and MongDB debug messages?

Comment: You're using some kind of logging middleware, you'll have to configure it to change the format or read the docs to understand what - and 961 means. My guess is that's the response size.

Comment: As far as errors go, you'll want to add an error handler to express.

Comment: can you show the code that is breaking?

Comment: Hi Alvaro, [this is the code that is breaking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33028273/cant-get-mongoose-to-give-me-a-list-of-documents-in-the-collection). Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Use [`node-inspector`](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) to be able to run your code under a real debugger so that you can set breakpoints, step through code, etc.

Comment: Hi JohnnyHK, thanks for letting me know! Can you show me how to use `node-inspector` with `npm start`? Please answer my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33090353/how-to-use-node-inspector-with-npm-start-for-my-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using node-inspector is very helpful. [This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33090353/4825465) showed me how to set it up in my case.