# How to use node-inspector with `npm start` for my application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mean-stack, node-inspector

I am using `npm start` to start my MEAN stack application, but I would like to use the node-inspector to debug some Mongoose. I know I can start the node inspector with `node-inspector`, but what can I substitute `node --debug app.js` with to make `npm start` work in my case?

This is my MEAN stack directory structure:

```
HTML        views/
Angular.js  public/javascript/
Express.js  routes/
Node.js     app.js
Mongoose js models/, connected in app.js
Mongo db    connected in app.js
```

For more information, this is my [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33026850/4825465).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may want to add a seperate `debug` script to `package.json`. That way you won't have to remember to revert `npm start` when you're finished debugging.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "debug": "node --debug ./bin/www"
}
```

Start with `npm run`:

```
$ npm run debug
```

Comment: DeprecationWarning: `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid. Please use `node --inspect` or `node --inspect-brk` instead.

Answer (score 3):

In `package.json` modify the `start` run command:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node --debug app.js"
}
```

Comment: Hi Moogs, thanks for your reply. Currently in my `"scripts"` it has: `"start": "node ./bin/www"`. What should I do to change it?

Comment: @Melissa try adding the `--debug` flag: `node --debug ./bin/www`

Answer (score 0):

I use it like this, I also set a variable and run the inspector in one command:
`npm run debug`

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "set SOAPAPI=https://example.com/&&nodemon",
  "debug": "start node-inspector --web-port=8081&&set SOAPAPI=https://example.com/&&nodemon --debug"
}
```

**[nodemon](http://nodemon.io/) is an utility wrapper for node, you can use `node` instead*